# Метот GET передача из текстового поля

Tags: php, html, post, get

Метод GET берет значение из

```
<input type="email" name="mail2" style="height: 30px; text-align: center;" x-autocompletetype="email" size="30" required>
```

и передает в конец строки нужного URL. Суть в том что URL содержит запрос, который заменяется моим.

В итоге вместо нужного:

```
http://www.сайт.com/?utm_source=NT&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=small&utm_campaign=rass_mail2=мыло
```

я получаю:

```
http://www.сайт.com/?mail2=мыло
```

Усложняет все это то, что нельзя использовать php и js

Код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>BELLAKT</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body style="max-width:400px; background: url(img/background.jpg) no-repeat;">
  <form action="http://www.сайт.com/?utm_source=NT&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=small&utm_campaign=rass_" method="get" target="_blank">
    <div style="padding-top: 230px; text-align: center;">
      <input type="email" name="mail2" style="height: 30px; text-align: center;" x-autocompletetype="email" size="30" required>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 8px; text-align: center;">
      <input type="submit" value="" style="background: url(img/btn.png)no-repeat center; width: 150px; height: 38px;">
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 300px"></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Без дополнительного вмешательства с помощью php или js нельзя сделать то, что вы задумали

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный примеры. Короткие однострочные комментарии не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить дополнительные параметры при отправке формы методом GET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703761/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-get)

Answer (score 1):

Без php и js вам надо убрать параметры из action в hidden input'ы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>BELLAKT</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body style="max-width:400px; background: url(img/background.jpg) no-repeat;">
  <form action="http://www.сайт.com" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="NT"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="cpc"/>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div style="padding-top: 230px; text-align: center;">
      <input type="email" name="mail2" style="height: 30px; text-align: center;" x-autocompletetype="email" size="30" required>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 8px; text-align: center;">
      <input type="submit" value="" style="background: url(img/btn.png)no-repeat center; width: 150px; height: 38px;">
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 300px"></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```