# Как добавить дополнительные параметры при отправке формы методом GET?

Tags: html, url, get

```
<form action="?route=category/create" method="GET">
    <input type="text" value="" name="cname" size="60" placeholder="Название категории" maxlength="255">
    <input type="text" value="" name="sub_cname" size="60" placeholder="Выбирете подкатегорию" maxlength="255">
    <input class="btn btn_default" type="submit" value="Создать">
</form>
```

Изначальный адрес странички для создания категории такой: `.../index.php?route=category/add`

после заполнения полей input и нажатии на кнопку submit в адресной строке адресс такой: `.../index.php?cname=test&sub_cname=` <-- получается, что я передаю параметры в index.php а мне нужно передать в `index.php?router=category/`

нужно/хочу что бы адрес был такой `test.my/admin/index.php?route=category/create&cname=test&sub_cname=`

То есть после нажатии на кнопку формы, `?route=category/create` удаляется из адресной строки

объясните, как это реализовать

Архив распакуйте в корень сайта. Адресс будет такой `yousitename.ru/admin/index.php?route=category/add`

На всякий случай прикрепляю [архив с кодом](http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachments/857667d1502227124)

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте скрытое поле с установленным значением:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="route" value="category/create">
    <input type="text" value="" name="cname" size="60" placeholder="Название категории" maxlength="255">
    <input type="text" value="" name="sub_cname" size="60" placeholder="Выбирете подкатегорию" maxlength="255">
    <input class="btn btn_default" type="submit" value="Создать">
</form>
```

Comment: добавил <input type="hidden" name="route" value="category/create"> теперь URL: ?route=category%2Fcreate&cname=test&sub_cname= откуда взялись символы %2F 

Но я теперь задумался что мне прийдеться такое делать с каждой формой, а это как то неправильно и глупо. 

Может подскажите что стоит изменить?

Comment: `%2F` это тот же `/`, но в соответствии со стандартом формирования url https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_URL На стороне сервера обычно идет автоматическая раскодировка символов. Если по какой-то причине ее нет, то в языках программирования есть функции для этого